# delete object through Django REST API

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to delete "Product" object using Django REST API but don't know how to do this.

serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'product_name', 'measure', 'barcode')
```

I can create product using this function

```
def create_product(request):
    data = request.POST
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
```

But I don't know how to delete

There is no serializer.delete() method.

Comment: Have your view inherit from the ModelViewSet(http://www.cdrf.co/3.7/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html). `destroy` is pretty much handled there with the rest of the CRUD functionality. You can set the `allowed_methods` property to allow only HTTP operations that you care about.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using query set:

```
@api_view(["DELETE"])
def product_delete_rest_endpoint(request, product_id):
    Product.objects.get(id=product_id).delete()
    return Response()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your view(set) inherits from `DestroyModelMixin`, or a viewset which inherit's from it, e.g. `ModelViewSet`, http `DELETE` is supported out of the box. You can test it with curl, for example `curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:8000/your-api/products/<product-id>"`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know how work with Router and ModelViewSet and GenericViewSet class from django rest_framework and instead of Product app let assume that you have Customer app.
you should inheritance your class viewset from viewsets.ModelViewSet or viewsets.GenericViewSet and mixins.DestroyModelMixin in views.py like blow

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
```

or

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
```

and define serilaizer class for that viewset like this

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
      serilaizer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

then you should define router for all request to api in your appName folder
and you should create urls.py file in that folder like below

> [you can see customer app folder in my project and urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB3Io.jpg)

in urls.py define router and url patterns like this

> [app_name variable define the name of url used by revers function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGzDO.png)

go to the urls.py in app folder (app/urls.py) and define path like below "*you should define a path to refer to customer/urls.py .. we create customer/urls.py in previous step*"

> [Define path in (app/urls.py)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHR4W.jpg)

OK .. run your project in browser and type your localhost address
http://(your localhost address)/api/customer/customers/1/ with DELETE request ( NOT POST, GET or PATCH request)

here is some link about router and viewset

> Router : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

> ModelViewSet: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

> Generic Viewset: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#genericviewset